# persistence volume with multiple local disks

Tags: kubernetes, local-storage, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I have a home Kubernetes cluster with multiple SSDs attached to one of the nodes.
I currently have one persistence volume per mounted disk. Is there an easy way to create a persistence volume that can access data from multiple disks? I thought about symlink but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to combine them at a lower level. The simplest approach would be Linux LVM but there's a wide range of storage strategies. Kubernetes orchestrates mounting volumes but it's not a storage management solution itself, just the last-mile bits.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by coderanger Kubernetes does not manage your storage at lower level. While with cloud solutions there might some provisioners that will do some of the work for you with bare metal there isn't.

The closest thing that help you manage local storage is [Local-volume-static-provisionner](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md).

> The local volume static provisioner manages the PersistentVolume
> lifecycle for pre-allocated disks by detecting and creating PVs for
> each local disk on the host, and cleaning up the disks when released.
> It does not support dynamic provisioning.

Have a look at [this](https://medium.com/alterway/kubernetes-local-static-provisioner-4c197e0f83ab#:%7E:text=The%20local%20volume%20static%20provisioner,does%20not%20support%20dynamic%20provisioning.) article for more example it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a trick which is working for me.
You can mount these disks at a directory like /disks/, and then make a loop filesystem, mounted it, and make a symbol link from disks to the loop filesystem.

for example:

```
touch ~/disk-bunch1 && truncate -s 32M ~/disk-bunch1 && mke2fs -t ext4 -F ~/disk-bunch1
```

mount it and make a symbol link from disks to the loop filesystem:

```
mkdir -p /local-pv/bunch1 && mount ~/disk-bunch1 /local-pv/bunch1
ln -s /disk/disk1 /local-pv/bunch1/disk1
ln -s /disk/disk2 /local-pv/bunch1/disk2
```

Finally, use [sig-storage-local-static-provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md), modify the "hostDir" to "/local-pv" in the values.yaml and deploy the provisioner. And then, you could make a pod use multiple disks.

But this method have a drawback, when you run "kubectl get pv", the CAPACITY is just the size of the loop filesystem instead of the sum of several disk capacities...

By the way, this method, is not recommended ... You'd better think of such as raid0 or lvm and etc...